# Change value with ID / or class but for one of the fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form when i have a lot of inputs that the user can add without limit. Every input has it's own ID:

```
#invoice_invoce_items_attributes_0_descripcion
#invoice_invoce_items_attributes_1_descripcion
#invoice_invoce_items_attributes_2_descripcion
#invoice_invoce_items_attributes_3_descripcion
```

Serialized. The value has to be changed based on a select input. The problem is that I don't know how to identify which ID to use, or how to serialize them.

If I use a class, all the values are updated.

Here is the code I am using it:

```
  function set_item_desc() {
  $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/admin/items/" + $(".like_table_cod").find("option:selected").val(),
        dataType: 'json',
        error: function() {
          var errorMsg = 'ERROR DE FUNCION.';
          console.log(errorMsg);
        },
        success: function(data) {
        $("#invoice_invoce_items_attributes_0_descripcion").val(data.descripcion);
        },
      });
  }
```

What can I do to identify the value to change?

Comment: Who calls that function and when?

Comment: Why different ID's? If you want to give the user unlimited fields I suggest using an array. ``<input type="text" name="invoice[]" value="foo">``

Comment: Thats why iam doing, i have name="invoice[]" attributes. The ids its because iam using rails and it automatically generates the ids based on the name attribute. But knowing that, how i can iterate the [] fields and idenfy which i have to change?

Comment: The function is called when the select input changes values.